# matlab parallel eigenvalue decomposition

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, eigenvector, eigenvalue, decomposition

It's been a wile I'm trying to come up with an algorithm for parallel eigenvalue decomposition, but non of the algorithms I tried can beat matlab's eig algorithm, so is there anyone who knows which algorithm does matlab use for the eig function ? 
or is can anyone suggest me a good parallel algorithm for eigenvalue decomposition ?

Answer (score 4):

MATLAB uses LAPACK for its higher level linear algebra.  According to MATLAB's version command, it is Intel's Math Kernel Library (MKL):

```
>> version('-lapack')
ans =
Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 11.0.2 Product Build 20130124 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications
Linear Algebra PACKage Version 3.4.1
```

Intel MKL includes very fast implementations of BLAS and LAPACK, but it is not free.  For open source options, try [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) and [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/).  Their APIs are very intuitive and they are quite fast.  And if you believe [Eigen's claims](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#How_does_Eigen_compare_to_BLAS.2FLAPACK.3F), they are the fastest open BLAS available with a superior API to the reference netlib LAPACK (IMO the API claim is pretty obvious once you take a look at the Fortran version!)

Comment: thanks a lot, but is there anything about making the algorithm parallel ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net) with [OpenBLAS](http://xianyi.github.io/OpenBLAS/).  Both are open source. Recent versions of OpenBLAS also provide LAPACK functions. OpenBLAS uses multiple cores (ie. runs in parallel).

When using Armadillo's [eig_sym()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eig_sym) function, specify that the divide-and-conquer method is to be used.  This makes a big difference on large matrices.  For example:

```
eig_sym(eigval, eigvec, X, "dc")
```

btw, you can also link Armadillo based code with Intel MKL instead of OpenBLAS. MKL also provides highly optimised LAPACK functions.